# Lodash and Graceful-fs

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2012, phonegap-desktop-app

i want to install phonegap in my pc so i can create my first hybrid app. I used `npm install -g phonegap` but i always get this error:

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\bufferu til\build\binding.sln : error : MSB3411 : Impossible de charger le composant  Visual C++ "VCBuild.exe". Si le composant n'est pas installé, vous devez 1)  installer le Kit de développement Microsoft Windows SDK pour Windows Server  2008 et .NET Framework 2.0 3.5, ou 2) installer Visual Studio 2008.
>   gyp ERR! build error
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>   gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\bufferutil
>   gyp ERR! node -v v5.6.0
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
>   gyp ERR! not ok
>   npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>   npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1

I'm sorry that the problem shown is in french, and it is written that i must install Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server  2008 and .NET Framework 2.0 or 3.5, or install Visual Studio 2008.

So i installed the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server  2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, but still got the same error + some errors related to Lodash and Graceful-fs' versions that i can't update, but have to be.

How can i update Lodash and Graceful-fs and have you guys any idea how to solve thatVCBuild.exe ? I couldn't find a solution on the internet

Answer (score 0):

I used `npm update -g lodash` to update lodash, and `npm update -g graceful-fs`.
And I think that the `-g` is important. Hope it will help.